# TFS reports finds wrong project after rename

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, tfs-reports

The problem is that alle the reports for a given project is now looking at a wrong team project.

In the standard reports the following query is used to determine the project:

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.ProjectNodeGUID, p.ProjectNodeName FROM
(
    SELECT ProjectNodeGUID, ProjectNodeName, 1 AS RowRank FROM GetProjectNodeInfoFromReportFolder(@ReportPath)
    UNION
    SELECT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' AS ProjectNodeGUID, 'missing' AS ProjectNodeName, 0 AS RowRank
) p ORDER BY p.RowRank DESC
```

But it does not return the correct one.

What has happened is that I renamed a project from `A` to `A.Old` and created a new project called `A`. 
Looking at the report server, there is no folder called A.Old, only `A` but that actually points to `A.Old`.

Any idea of how to fix that?

Comment: Hi Michael, after renaming a team project, for reports, they will reflect new names after the next **incremental analysis** job runs for the data warehouse. By default it runs every two hours. To expedite the process, manually run the [warehouse jobs and incremental analysis job](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube) so the new name gets synced to warehouse and reports start using the new name. Reports will not work as expected until the jobs have run. If you got a conflict  in collection database, suggest you restore the database backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to the Warehouse for TFS then you will need to run a rebuild of the Warehouse to have this change passed through. This is true for Project Renames, Deletes, and Collection detach/attach.

This should have been displayed in the warning message when you did the rename.

Running a rebuild from the admin console will fix this...

Comment: Yeah, I read that too and did the rebuild. A couple of times actually. But no luck. I suspecting that somethings is wrong in the Collection database. Maybe because I created a new project with the same name as the old one, before jobs ran??

Comment: Could you check event log in Event Viewer to see if there is any helpful information?

Comment: I did the rename several month ago. That's gonna be like finding a needle in a haystack. I will see if I can find something, but the time of the rename is unknown.

Comment: Did you do a full rebuild of the warehouse or just an inremental?

Comment: In the TFS admin Console under Reporting I clicked the `Start Rebuild` button. I noticed that the database got empty before it got re-populated, so I guess it was a full rebuild.

Comment: I can also see that the project names in tables `dbo.tbl_Project` and `dbo.tbl_projects` does not match. `dbo_tbl_projects` has the correct name.